# Multiple Service Layer and Repository Pattern managed with Events

Tags: service, repository

I know that this could be another topic regarting service layer and repository pattern, but "I still haven't found what I'm looking for" ( U2 docet ... )

I'm working with a complex application with dozen of services and repositories; the pattern, to show an example, could be like this:

```
Controller
$return = $this->getUserService()->findAll();

class UserService
public function findAll()
return $this->getUserRepository()->findAll();

class UserRepository
/**
* 
* @return Collection of UserModel
*/
public function findAll(){
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `user` ";        
return $this->fetchAll($sql);
}
```

So, for every Table in database, there are these entities:

```
{Entity}Service
{Entity}Repository
{Entity}Model
```

In the controller, I have a collection of UserModel objects, returned back from repository layer through  the service layer.

All sounds good, until we work with a single table; how do you usually work if you have to work with multiple services/repositories?

1) question number 1

Let I want to send an email after an operation and increase a stats; I could do this in the controller, but probabply in the service layer it could be better, cause
in service layer you should add your business logic.

So I could write:

```
Controller
    $this->getUserService()->doSomething($params);

class UserService
    public function doSomething($params);

    $ok = $this->getUserRepository()->do($params);
    $this->getMailService()->sendEmail($params);
    $this->getStatsService()->updateStats($params);

    return true;
```

In this way, I have to add many services access to a single service; is it right? 
if all these three operations are strictly correlated , this is the right way cause you can move  service method elsewhere without problems ( API context, Web context), and all the operations will remanin intact.
The problem is that you have to inject services within the UserService, for example using a service container.
What do you think? how do you proceed if you have to perform many operations together? Do you use controller instead?

2) question 2

I have a collection of UserModels fetched from this pattern ( Controller > Service > Repository > Service > Controller)
Let I have a UserModel with a dependency, for example a the list of Posts written by the User, and I want to be able to load the list of Posts in a lazy way.

How can I archieve this? 
My User Repository has returned only rows from user table from the database, and I don't want to add joins, cause I could not want to load posts at every request.
Another problem is that  Post Models belongs to another Service > Repository ( PostService and PostRepository )

I solve this problems using events; basically, every requests to dependency object fire an event.

```
class UserModel
    protected $posts = null;

    public function setPosts($posts)
    $this->posts = $posts;

    public function getPosts()
        if(is_null($this->posts))
            $this->loadPosts();
        return $this->posts;

    protected function loadPost()
        Event::trigger(Event::LOAD_POST,['targetModel' => $this]);

Controller

    $users = $this->getUserService()->findAll();
    foreach($users as $user){
        $posts = $user->getPosts();
    }
    ...


$eventEmitter->on(Event::LOAD_POST, function(Event $e) {
    $targetModel = $e->getData('targetModel');
    if (!method_exists($targetModel, 'setPosts')) {
        return false;
    }
    $posts = $e->getContainer()
    ->get('post-service')
    ->findByUserId($targetModel->getUserId());
    $targetModel->setPosts($posts);
    return true;
});
```

Basically, when I ask the list of the posts to the model and the related model property is  NULL ( not empty, but NULL ), I trigger an event, passing the object  I'm in.
The trigger call a function that has been registered during application bootstrap, who call the right services and call the targetModel setter to load objects.

In this way, I solve many problems; I can separate services and avoid too many services within other services.
I can also reuse this code; let I have many entities with $posts, I can create a PostTrait with property , setter and getter, and use it in all entities who 
has to manage a list  of posts.

What do you think about this solution? If there is another way to load object from different repository in a lazy way, without mixing repositories, tell me!

Thanks in advance!